# Command-Line Arguments Being Lost?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I'm writing a Java program to clean some data.

I'm passing it the files I need, but the first file is ignored!

Minimum code to reproduce the issue:

```
public class Classifier {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    for (String s : args) {
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running it with the following Command-Line Argument:

```
java Classifier < March.csv February.csv
```

And the output I'm receiving is:

```
February.csv February.csv
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `< March.csv` is being interpreted by the shell as an input redirect.  The contents of `March.csv` are sent to your program's standard input, which you are ignoring.  This happens in the shell, before your Java program is even started.  So, only `February.csv` is being sent as a command line argument to `main`.

Remove that `<`, so that all command-line arguments you intended to send to `main` are sent.

Answer (score 1):

`<` operator redirects this file to stdin to this Java process

so

if you just have

```
java Classifier < March.csv
```

and try to read arguments, you would see none and if you read stdin you would read the file content